# Last Fm API returns nothing with specific time period

Tags: json, api, last.fm

I'm using the last fm api to get data from a user but when using the `User.getTopTracks` method with the time period `1month`, it returns nothing:

```
{
  toptracks: {
    #text: " ",
    user: "RJ",
    type: "1month",
    page: "",
    perPage: "",
    totalPages: "",
    total: "0"
  }
}
```

This error does not occur when using similar methods (e.g. `User.getTopAlbums`)

Comment: Can you provide some code for example? I want to see how do you call method.

Comment: @VladGolubev I'm using sinatra so I make a request like this: `Net::HTTP.get(URI("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=User.getTopTracks&user=amosjackson&api_key=XXXXXXXXXX&period=1month&format=json"))`

Comment: It isn't your fault. Seems like we use &period parametr wrong. I can't get response too. 

    `$.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettoptracks&period=1month&user=samosfator&api_key=XXXX&format=json', function(response) {result = response}).done(function (result) {console.log(result)})`


The most probable variant is that last.fm's api has changed. I'll inform you as soon as I found solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the Last.fm API.

The issue [used to exist](http://www.last.fm/group/Last.fm+Web+Services/forum/21604/_/2078342) for `getTopArtists` as well. It has been fixed for the artists call, but not for `getTopTracks`.

My solution is to use `3month` when the user selects `1month`. If I have time I will update the UI to work around this issue.